# How can I add a specific page to the 'New Tab' page?

Tags: firefox

In the Firefox 13, Mozilla added the new tabs homepage.

> The [New Tab](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRp4a_24cp8) page now opens whenever you click on the '+' sign,
>   allowing you to see thumbnails of your most recently and frequently
>   visited sites. You can customize the New Tab page by adding or
>   removing thumbnails based on where you go most.

Is there a way to add specific pages to this tabs page?  Currently I'm removing tabs as they appear and it would be better if I could add the specific ones I want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To do this you have to make your specific site to bookmark and then drag that bookmark from library to the **New Tab** page on a thumbnail. You can also pin tabs in the order you want them to appear.

[Mozilla support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites?s=about%3Anewtab&r=0&e=es&as=s#w_add-a-site) have a page where they tell you how to do it.

Comment: Exactly, you can drop from any firefox's item like bookmark, history,... to the new tab. It's open :3

Comment: This still works on Firefox 56, and seems to be the only working approach on this version.

Answer (score 3):

I just did this and it worked for me: I went to recent history and dragged the site I wanted over to an empty thumbnail spot after I deleted a bunch I didn't want. It was a lucky try after trying many other things. Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

The link in the answer by Sheldrake/Avirk does work, but be careful to do it exactly as described.  It doesn't work dragging from the Bookmarks drop-down list (doing that will just go to the bookmarked page).  You have to select the "show all bookmarks" from the bookmark drop-down to get the bookmark organizer window with the tree-type navigation to open up.  Bookmarks can be dragged from the list in that window to the thumbnail page (assuming you went to that new tab page first).

I don't know why there is still no link or instruction for this on the actual thumbnail page.

Answer (score 0):

Just select, drag and drop the full url address **from browser's address bar** on top of one of the empty cells in the New Tab tab.
There is no need to add it to your bookmarks prior doing this.

Comment: I tried this, but it just opened the URL in the current tab instead of adding it to the new tab tile.

Answer (score -1):

As far as my knowledge and research over the net, there is NO SOLUTION for this. The method, the Firefox mentions, doesn't work at all. I have tried in fresh OS installation with latest service pack and Windows Update and in latest Firefox versions many times. I am unable to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

what you need is to type about:config in the url and press enter

then click I promise I'll be careful

next in the search bar that appears type browser and press enter

next with the page down locate the browser.newtab.url

once on it press enter and replace about:blank with eg http://www.google.co.uk

from then on every time you press the + you get that web page.

enjoy

Comment: This isn't quite what he is looking for. He is referring to a new feature in Firefox 13+ that has a bunch of bookmarks on the new tab page.