# How can I undo removing a page from the new tab page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, speed-dial

I accidentally clicked the X button on one of my pages in the new “Speed Dial” tab page in Firefox.

How can I undo this operation? I'm fine with editing a config file or SQLite database in my profile, I just need to know where to make the change.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/435678/in-firefox-how-can-i-add-a-specific-page-to-the-new-tab-page/435682#435682).

Answer (score 1):

Add desired site to bookmarks, then open bookmarks panel and use Drag-n-Drop to move your site to Speed Dial screen.